# how boost::~shared_ptr works?

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr

when reading "Beyond the C++ Standard Library: An Introduction to Boost " ,I got a very interesting example:

```
class A  
{  
public:  
    virtual void sing()=0;  
protected:  
    virtual ~A() {};  
};

class B : public A
{  
public:  
    virtual void sing(  )  
    {  
       std::cout << "Do re mi fa so la"<<std::endl;;  
    }  
};
```

and I do some testing:

```
int main()
{  

//1  
std::auto_ptr<A> a(new B); //will not compile ,error: ‘virtual A::~A()’ is protected

//2
A *pa = new B;
delete pa;  //will not compile ,error: ‘virtual A::~A()’ is protected
delete (dynamic_cast<B*>(pa)); //ok

//3 
boost::shared_ptr<A> a(new B);//ok

}
```

what I am very curious here is  how ~shared_ptr works?
how it deduce the derived class B ?

Thanks advance for your help!

thanks all,
I write a simple sample about how ~shared_ptr works

```
class sp_counted_base
{
public:
    virtual ~sp_counted_base(){}
};

template<typename T>
class sp_counted_base_impl : public sp_counted_base
{
public:
    sp_counted_base_impl(T *t):t_(t){}
    ~sp_counted_base_impl(){delete t_;}
private:
    T *t_;
};


class shared_count
{
public:
    static int count_;
    template<typename T>
    shared_count(T *t):
        t_(new sp_counted_base_impl<T>(t))
    {
        count_ ++;
    }
    void release()
    {
        --count_;
        if(0 == count_) delete t_;
    }
    ~shared_count()
    {
        release();
    }
private:
    sp_counted_base *t_;
};
int shared_count::count_(0);

template<typename T>
class myautoptr
{
public:
    template<typename Y>
    myautoptr(Y* y):sc_(y),t_(y){}
    ~myautoptr(){ sc_.release();}
private:
    shared_count sc_;
    T *t_;
};

int main()
{
    myautoptr<A> a(new B);
}
```

the key is:

1. template construct function
2. the resource not deleted in ~shared_ptr ,it is deleted by shared_count

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Surprisingly, the key here is not `boost::shared_ptr` destructor but its constructor(s).

If you look into `boost/shared_ptr.hpp`, you will see that `shared_ptr<T>` does not 'simply' have a constructor expecting a `T *` but :

```
template<class Y>
explicit shared_ptr( Y * p );
```

In `//3` when you construct a `boost::shared_ptr` from a `B *`, no conversion to `A *` takes place, and the `shared_ptr` internals are built with the actual `B` type. Upon destruction of the object, deletion occurs on a `B` pointer (not through a base class pointer).

Comment: Technically speaking, it DOES perform a conversion from B* to A*. All subsequent accesses to the pointer will use the type A*. Operations on type B are via standard polymorphism (they go through A*). The only exception is the destructor, which shared_ptr remembers via its "deleter" mechanism (or some generalization thereof).

Answer (score 3):

The `shared_ptr` class template has a member of class type `shared_count`, which in turn has a member of type pointer to class `sp_counted_base`. The constructor template for class `shared_count` assigns a pointer to an instance of the class template `sp_counted_impl_p` to this member which is templated by the type of the constructor argument, not by the `shared_ptr::value_type`. `sp_counted_base` has a pure virtual member function `dispose` which is overwritten by `sp_counted_impl_p`. Because `sp_counted_impl_p` knows the type `B` in your example, it can delete it without access to the base class destructor, and because it uses virtual dispatch, the type is determined at runtime. This method requires a combination of parametric and subtype polymorphism.